# Hover on svg for affecting the other element property doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

HTML:

```
<div>
<svg class="velveti-grid-point" width="100" height="100" style="height: 120px; width: 625px;">
       <circle class="myPoint" cx="500" cy="105" r="5" fill="#80E1EE" />
</svg>
    <div class="theContainer">bg-color</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myPoint:hover + .theContainer {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Problem: When i am hovering on the blue svg circle the background-color should be displayed on the text, but with svg it doesn't work. What is the problem? what do i need to do?

The demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wy6y66ox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SVG *per se*.

`+` is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element.

Because `.myPoint` is not a sibling of `.theContainer` your selector will not work.

You would need javascript in this instance.

Comment: Thank you, i got it! But ill better do it with jQuery i think, just for shorter writing.

Answer (score 1):

Paulie_D is right.You have to use Javascript.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<svg  class="velveti-grid-point" width="100" height="100" style="height: 120px; width: 625px;">
       <circle id="svgid" class="myPoint" cx="500" cy="105" r="5" fill="#80E1EE" />
</svg>
    <div id="divcolor" class="theContainer">bg-color</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var svg = document.getElementById( 'svgid' );
var div = document.getElementById( 'divcolor' );
svg.onmouseover = function() {


  div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};
svg.onmouseout = function() {

  div.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
};
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wy6y66ox/2/)**

Comment: I am glad this helped you.